# Why is SQLite implicitly inserting on update of non-existing row?

Tags: sqlite

So I'm using SQLite with .NET and System.Data.SQLite library (which shouldn't be relevant to the question). I'm executing a simple UPDATE statement with a WHERE clause, such that 0 rows should be affected. Instead, SQLite inserts a new row satisfying the provided WHERE clause.

I've read through SQLite documentation on UPDATE statement, but couldn't find anything about this feature. Googling around also doesn't seem to help. Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: Anything more specific? Using `sqlite3` on the command line (in memory), I can't reproduce the problem with a simple example: `CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, val INTEGER); INSERT INTO test(val) VALUES(10); UPDATE test SET id=11 WHERE id=10;`

Comment: Hi Bruno, scenario where this happens is swapping of values between two sets of records. A set of records has a key-like common value on the field being swapped. I use 3 update commands: set value to "TEMP" where value = A; set value to "A" where value = "B", set value to "B" where value = "TEMP";   This is all done via .NET SQLite ilbrary, using SQLiteCommand with parameters.  The issue appears when there are no record(s) for with "B", so either the library or some piece along the way is inserting a row. No INSERT statements are explicitly executed by me, only 3 UPDATE statements.

Comment: Please make a MCVE stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
For SQLIte, an MCVE includes a `.dump` of your SQLITE database.